In CATIA V5 how can I open or call my catscripts, catvba and vbas from winform?
I developing a Catia time save toolbar for my needs in C#. But I new in C# and I didn't figure it out how to call my catscripts or etc.
I tried something like this but I failed. What should I do? Thank you.
namespace CatiaAutomation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            RunCatScript();

        }



        private void RunCatScript()

        {
            Application catiaApp;

            try

            {

                catiaApp = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("CATIA.Application");

            }

            catch (COMException)

            {

                MessageBox.Show("CATIA çalışmıyor.");

                return;

            }
            try
            {
                string scriptPath = "C:\\catscripts\\deneme.CATScript\\";          catiaApp.SystemService.Evaluate("CATIA.StartCommand(\"" + scriptPath + "\");");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("CATScript çalıştırılamadı: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}


Please have a look onto the ExecuteScript function of the Catia.SystemService

@shrotter I didn't figure it out but thanks sir. catiaApp.SystemService.ExecuteScript(scriptPath, "catscript", "", null); But still not works. I didnt understand this ExecuteScript

for a CATScript the call of the function should be like: .ExecuteScript (PathToFolder, catScriptLibraryTypeDirectory, FileNameOfScript, NameOfRoutine, params)

@Shrotter Hello sir It's now working perfectly :D I did what you said now works very nicely. catiaApp.SystemService.ExecuteScript(scriptPath, CatScriptLibraryType.catScriptLibraryTypeDirectory, "AxisEkleme.CATScript", "CATMain",null);

With the help of Shrotter, I solved like this:
catiaApp.SystemService.ExecuteScript(scriptPath, CatScriptLibraryType.catScriptLibraryTypeDirectory, "AxisEkleme.CATScript", "CATMain",null);

